Do people play variants in chess clubs?
The club that I've gone to plays standard chess format, forty five minutes on the clock, with an increment of fifteen seconds, which seems to be the regular way of playing for over-the-board chess.
I was just wondering if any clubs that people go to play the various variants on the standard chess rules. This being: the layout of the pieces, the conclusion parameters, the affect of captures etc.
The variants that could be played include, the following:

Fischer random (Chess 960),
King of the hill
Three check
Atomic
Racing kings
Crazyhouse
Antichess/Giveaway/Losing chess
Horde

Are such variants are played at your clubs and, if so, to what degree of success the clubs have with their being played?
Perhaps there are other variants that I've never heard of that may get played online too?

Which variant do you mean by Anti-chess? (Is it Losing chess, by any chance? I guess so but I'd rather be sure.) What is Hoard?

Are surveys on topic?

I don't think there's anything "standard" about the 45+15 time control. In my club we usually do 3+2 or 5+0 (with a lot of 2v2 chess as well)

Obviously this is hard to answer any differently than just anecdotally, but from my experience in Germany at least Bughouse, Antichess, and Atomic are a fairly popular pastime among kids in clubs and at tournaments, and Bughouse more generally also among adults and even top players.
However, generally I would say chess variants at clubs usually are only played very casually if at all, and chess variant enthusiasts mostly meet either online or separately from dedicated chess clubs.
